# consume ASP.NET Web API functionality on another Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, httpclient

I'm using microservices architecture on my server side with ASP.NET CORE web API. I have one database and one table but I'm separating the properties while converting to EF to represent the separation between the database, like this:

[image]

So that on one first solution (microservice)- called UserControl I have:

```
[Table("User")]
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string UserName { get; set; } = null!;
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }

}
```

And on the other solution (microservice)- called ContactsControl I have:

```
[Table("User")]
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string? DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a registration form (my client is on Angular) that includes both of the solutions – meaning that Post method on UserControl should add and update the entire table:

- Guid Id
- UserName
- Password
- **DisplayName**

Like a real Registration Form.
I understand that I need to consume the functionality from  ContactsControl – I think I need to call on my UserControl Post Method (registration) the Update method from  ContactsControl after I'm adding the UserControl properties. I know I need to use HttpClient but I'm not sure how to use it and where?

UserControl repository:

```
 public Guid Add(User user)
    {
        _context.Users.Add(user);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return user.Id;
        // **call Put method from ContactUser By using HttpClient and Response**

    }
```

UserControl Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] UserPostDTO user)
    {
        _userRepository.Add(user.ToPostUser());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before saving the current system, you should send the user information to another system for verification. Suppose we need to compare the mobile phone number. If it exists, return the registered prompt.

When the verification is passed, the registration information can be saved at the same time, and the execution result can be returned. Of course, all the registered information can be returned, and then merged in the current system or save the required value. Ensure data consistency. If the verification fails, just return to the prompt.

---

**Method in ContactsControl**

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] UserPostDTO user)
{
    // Before the current system saves, the data is first forwarded to 
    // UserControl for verification, The verification is passed, 
    // or after saving, the result is returned, assuming true

    var validResult =await _httpClient.GetAsync(" call UserControl method to vaild or save");

    // The judgment condition is just a demonstration, 
    // you can also judge according to the return value

    if(validResult.StatusCode== 201 ){
       // save in current system
       _userRepository.Add(user.ToPostUser());
    }else{
       // save or cancel this operation
       
    }
    
    ...
}
```

---

#### How to use `HttpClient` in .Net 5

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    // add this line
    services.AddHttpClient();
    ...
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

**Controller**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    // add this line
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    private IHostEnvironment _iHostingEnvironment;
    private readonly ILogger<TestController> _logger;

    public TestController(ILogger<TestController> logger, IHostEnvironment iHostingEnvironment, HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _iHostingEnvironment = iHostingEnvironment;
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused: `public void Post([FromBody] UserPostDTO user)` is on **UserControl** and you said I should change my post action on Method in ContactsControl. Also I dont understand - if I'm calling GetAsync("call UserControl method") from ContactsControll , I still don't understand how it's activating both POST to database. If my client is making post request, let's say to ContactsControll , inside the action when I', reaching GetAsync the fields will be empty, Am I right?